# How can I run a Program, and have it continue when the remote console disconnects

Tags: linux, sh

I want to run my Java Program on my Raspberry Pi, but it needs to continue running even if i close Putty. The Program is running on my Raspberry Pi and it is starting completely fine, but as soon as I close the console the Program stops.

I can tell it stops because after closing There wont be any Logs into the log fille (except the ones from before closing the Putty Terminal)

Currently I tried it with an sh script and this line within it:

`nohup java -jar /home/pi/Programms/PantaBot/PantaBot.jar  > /var/log/logPantaBot.txt 2>&1 &`

and with running the sh script with
`sh startScript.sh&`

The sh Script:

```
chmod 777 HandballDBFiller-1.0.0.jar
java -jar HandballDBFiller-1.0.0.jar > ~/Programme/HandballTippspiel/Log.txt
```

Comment: This question should really have been asked on superuser rather than stackoverflow - stackoverflow is just for programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using something like [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) or [tmux](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) - they both allow you to launch "persistent" terminals that you can disconnect and reconnect to later - possibly from somewhere else, without killing processes launched from such terminals.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a program capable of detaching processes such as [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki).

Comment: the "this question should really" part should have been a comment. Also, you beat me to the answer by 20s :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux).

> tmux is a terminal multiplexer. It lets you switch easily between several programs in one terminal, detach them (they keep running in the background) and reattach them to a different terminal.

You can detach the current session and attach to it when connecting through ssh again.

Expect a learning curve - it takes some time to get used to it.